# Citation type for a NIST Publications

Tags: citations, ieee

In my masters thesis I need to cite from "[NIST Special Publication 800-22](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/legacy/sp/nistspecialpublication800-22r1a.pdf)". 
We are to use IEEE referencing style and I am using an online LaTeX editor to get this done.

Now that this document I need to refer to is a PDF document, I have no idea what is the type of the document that I should treat it as. Is that okay if I treat it as an article? Or else is there any other type that it should fall under?

Comment: Perhaps a “report” is more suites for a NIST publication.

Comment: @TheGuy I am currently going with that choice actually.. but I need something profound. Thank you very much for your time.. :) Much appreciated!

Comment: I can get it on a [google scholar search](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=NIST+special+publication+800+22&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=2010&as_yhi=2010). If you click on the "quotes", it’ll show you how to cite it and you can opt for bibtex if that’s what you need. Be warned, though, they’re **not always perfect** (but will give enough information for others to find your reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in my field, NIST special publications and technical notes are cited as handbooks or reports. In particular, I'd cite that as follows:

> A. Rukhin et al., "A Statistical Test Suite for Random and
>   Pseudorandom Number Generators for Cryptographic Applications", *NIST
>   Special Publication 800-22*, US Department of Commerce, National
>   Institute of Standards and Technology, Gaithersburg, MD, April 2010.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.. :)